# VBA Excel - run macro base on several cells value (multiple cells)

Tags: excel, vba

I have some fast (or at least I think so) question about VBA. I have a code attached below which works pretty well, but I must modify it a bit - and get errors all the time.

What I must achiev is: testing not only **cell L7**, but also **L8** **separately**, so in practice:

if value of **L7** is **a** run **macro_a**
(this is working well) but at the same time, when value of **L8** is **k** I must run **macro_k** or if the **L8** is **m**, **macro_m** etc

how it can be done ?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L7")) Is Nothing Then
If Target.Value = "a" Then macro_a
If Target.Value = "b" Then macro_b
If Target.Value = "c" Then macro_c
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need to check the intersect and then check target address using If or Select Case to identify the cell changed.

Comment: Presumably, you need to get the value of L8.

Comment: Im trying but get errors all the time, I would appreciate a lot if you could edit my code (if its not too much work).

Comment: Don't use the intersect, just use `target.address` and as SJR says `if` or `select case` on that.

Comment: to be quite frank i just starting learning vba, not sure how should I modify code to implement those things you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will check if either, or both, cells L7/L8 have been changed and then run the appropriate macros based on which cell(s) have changed and the value(s) in the cell(s).

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cl As Range

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L7:L8")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cl In Target
            If cl.Address(0, 0) = "L7" Then
                Select Case cl.Value
                    Case "a":
                        macro_a
                    Case "b"
                        macro_b
                    Case "c"
                        macro_c
                End Select
            End If
            If cl.Address(0, 0) = "L8" Then
                Select Case cl.Value
                    Case "k"
                        macro_k
                    Case "m"
                        macro_m
                End Select
            End If
        Next cl
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Good point, I'll adjust the code.

Comment: norie it works great :) thank you a lot. Bonus question, is there any way of making condition `Case "k"` for different than "k" ?

Comment: Ive made '  Case Is <> "k" ' and it works, once more thank you very much

Comment: Could this be simplified to something along these lines? `case "a" or "b" or "c" Application.Run ("macro_" & cl.Value)`  I'm assuming these are the actual names of the macro's in saying this :o)

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Yes, if the macros were actually called `macro_a` etc you could use `Application.Run "macro_" & cl.Value`.

Comment: that was just example to simplify, not always macro will be called macro_a while condition to check is also "a"